# array traversal vs pointer, cache efficiency aspect

Tags: c++, arrays, caching, pointers

```
void foo(Node* p[], int size){

    _uint64 arr_of_values[_MAX_THREADS];


    for (int i=0 ; i < size ; i++ ){
         arr_of_values[i] = p[i]->....;

         // much code here 
         // 
      }
 }
```

vs

```
void foo(Node* p[], int size){

    _uint64 arr_of_values[_MAX_THREADS];

    Node* p_end = p[size];
    for ( ; p != p_end ; ){            
         arr_of_values[i] = (*p)->.....;
         p++;


         // much code here 
         // 
     }

}
```

I created this function to demonstrate what i am asking:

what is more efficient from the cache efficiency aspect : taking p[i] or using *p++?

(i'll never use the p[i-x] in the rest of the code, but i may use p[i] or *p in the following calculation)

Comment: what is more efficient from cache aspect , increasing p and then loading *p OR increasing the counter i and asking *(p+i) ?

Comment: Cachewise, there's no difference.  At most there could be a data dependency difference (but the compiler should optimize that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem from a cache point of view isn't the way you are accessing the elements. In this case using a pointer or the array index is equivalent.

BTW Node* p[] is an array of pointer. So you could have possibly allocated your Node objects into distant memory areas. (For example using several ptr = new Node()). The best cache performance are gainable if:

1. Your Node are stored contiguosly into memory
2. Node size doesn't exceed the cache size.

Answer (score 2):

the most important is to avoid [false sharing](http://herbsutter.com/2009/05/15/effective-concurrency-eliminate-false-sharing/) in the `arr_of_values`. Each thread write into its own slot, but 8 or 16 slots share a cache line (depending on CPU) causing a massive false sharing problem. Add padding between the slots to cache align each thread's slot, or accumulate on stack and write only once at the end:

```
void foo(Node* p[], int size){

    _uint64 arr_of_values[_MAX_THREADS];

    Node* p_end = p[size];
    for ( ; p != p_end ; ){            
         temp = .....;
         p++;
         // much code here 
         // 
     }  
     arr_of_values[i] = temp;
}
```

the question of access by pointer or access by index is irrelevant with today's compiler.s

Your next actions should be: grab a copy of [the Software optimization Cookbook](http://www.intel.com/intelpress/sum_swcb2.htm). Read it. Measure. Fix the measured hotspot, not the guesstimates.

Comment: This would be a great answer if there were any threads involved at all... but this appears to be a question about sequential code.

Comment: @_BenVoigt: Agreed, but I took a leap of faith and assumed that the array being dimensioned by `[_MAX_THREADS]` is used as one slot-per-thread.

Comment: Remus- you are right, actually this snippet is based on a complicated code with multiple hierarchy of multiple threads that merge items from multiple queues into local queues +then more threads merge items from those local queues into a central. my code has bad performance, and i believe that the bottleneck is this function which iterates over multiple queues: i have an option to increase the pointer on that queue or to iterate over it with and index. false sharing is very relevant here.

Comment: @Michael: also [The Art of Multiprocessor Programming](http://www.amazon.com/The-Multiprocessor-Programming-Maurice-Herlihy/dp/0123705916), highly recommended. It has examples of exactly what you're trying to do, albeit using Java (many algorithms are *a lot* easier when you have GC)

Comment: But really, your best bet is to *measure* right now. VTune, F1 Profiler. Find the hot spots and then address them.

Comment: @Michael: You're asking a question about performance, and cache behavior specifically, and didn't mention that you have multiple threads?  Please try to include important information in your future questions.

Comment: If you are familiar with profiles for Solaris (Sun), it will be halpfull, currently i use cputrack (i am writing over cc compiler)